# How do I add chromedriver to PATH?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to follow Automate the Boring Stuff and am trying to do the selenium work. I’m running Linux using Mu. Here's the code I'm trying to run

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = “/lorenmspeer/Downloads/chromedriver.exe”
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)

url = “https://www.duckduckgo.com”
browser.get(url)
```

I’m getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/lorenmspeer/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210401-164244/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py”, line 72, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py”, line 854, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py”, line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/lorenmspeer/Downloads/chromedriver.exe’

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/lorenmspeer/mu_code/seleniumTest22.py”, line 5, in
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
File “/home/lorenmspeer/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210401-164244/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py”, line 73, in init
self.service.start()
File “/home/lorenmspeer/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210401-164244/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py”, line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ‘chromedriver.exe’ executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Did you try to provide path like that: `chromedriver = “/home/lorenmspeer/Downloads/chromedriver.exe”`

Answer (score 0):

To check where Chrome driver is installed on Linux run `whereis chromedriver`.  Then, put this path to Chrome("your_path")
In my project it is specified in the folder I defined:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

It should **not** have `.exe` resolution

For more info check docs:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. First I had to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

Then I moved it to PATH

```
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
```

This made the code launch the browser.